# Identify columns that have only 0 values

Tags: r

I would like some help with the following question:

As you can see the executable code below it generates a graph with dots and a line. These points are generated from my `df1` dataset. But notice that there are some DR that are only 0, for example, the DR09, DR10 and DR12. So I'd like to do some function or something that idenfied when all DRs are 0, and that weren't considered when calculating my `datas` variable, because as it is, it's considering the whole `df1` dataset.

Thank you very much!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Monday"),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),
       DR08 = c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0),DR09 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR010 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR011 = c(0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0), DR012 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

#Generate graph

dmda<-"2021-07-01"

datas<-df1 %>%
  filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(name = as.numeric(name))
colnames(datas)<-c("Days","Numbers")

attach(datas)
plot(Numbers ~ Days, ylim=c(0,20))

model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 47,b2 = 0))

new.data <- data.frame(Days = seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45))
lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may do this with `select` i.e. check whether the column is numeric (`is.numeric`) and `where` `all` the values are 0

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    select(where(~ is.numeric(.) && all(. == 0))) %>% 
    names
[1] "DR09"  "DR010" "DR012"
```

If we want to select columns that doesn't include them, then negate (`!`)

```
df1 %>%
    select(!where(~ is.numeric(.) && all(. == 0)))
        date1      date2     Week DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR011
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday    4    4    9    5    5    2    2    0     0
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday    1    2    5    4    4    4    5    0     4
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday    4    6    4    3    5    3    4    0     0
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday    3    7    3    3    3    3    4    1     0
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday    3    3    3    6    6    5    9    2     0
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday    4    2    2    2    2    6    4    0     0
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday    3    7    1    1    1    7    7    0     0
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03   Monday    6    4    5    9    9    8    8    0     0
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
names(which(sapply(df1, function(x) is.numeric(x) && all(x == 0))))
[1] "DR09"  "DR010" "DR012"
```

Comment: Perfect akrun, just one thing:  if I want to select from the Week column to those DR that don't have 0, how do I do it? Before I did something like this: `select(Week:DR11)`

Comment: @JSouza Is that the update in my post you wanted `df1 %>%
    select(!where(~ is.numeric(.) && all(. == 0)))`

Comment: @JSouza what i meant is that in the first block it just matches the columns that are having all 0 and select it.  In the second case, just negate (`!`) so that the rest of the columns are selected

Answer (score 2):

We could use `colSums`:

```
df1[, colSums(df1 != 0) > 0]
```

output:

```
       date1      date2     Week DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR011
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday    4    4    9    5    5    2    2    0     0
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday    1    2    5    4    4    4    5    0     4
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday    4    6    4    3    5    3    4    0     0
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday    3    7    3    3    3    3    4    1     0
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday    3    3    3    6    6    5    9    2     0
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday    4    2    2    2    2    6    4    0     0
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday    3    7    1    1    1    7    7    0     0
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03   Monday    6    4    5    9    9    8    8    0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Filter` with `any` -

```
Filter(function(x) any(x != 0), df1)

#       date1      date2     Week DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR011
#1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday    4    4    9    5    5    2    2    0     0
#2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday    1    2    5    4    4    4    5    0     4
#3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday    4    6    4    3    5    3    4    0     0
#4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday    3    7    3    3    3    3    4    1     0
#5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday    3    3    3    6    6    5    9    2     0
#6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday    4    2    2    2    2    6    4    0     0
#7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday    3    7    1    1    1    7    7    0     0
#8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03   Monday    6    4    5    9    9    8    8    0     0
```

Similar logic can also be implemented using `keep` and `discard` function in `purrr`.

```
purrr::keep(df1, ~any(.x != 0))
purrr::discard(df1, ~all(.x == 0))
```